# Can i #define void for a swig library?

Tags: python, c, swig

I am trying to use SWIG to generate a python interface module for a library that I do not control the source of. The library, for some reason, has this line:

```
#define VOID void
```

This is causing all kinds of issues with SWIG; it seems to think that VOID is an actual object that these functions will return.

Is there any way i can tell SWIG that `VOID` means `void`?

Comment: The library was probably designed to work with pre-ANSI C compilers that didn't support the `void` keyword; for such compilers, it would probably have `#define VOID int` or `#define VOID /* nothing */`. This doesn't answer your question, though.

Comment: You say you don't have control over the source of the library, but you have the headers. I think you should be able to rename VOID to something else (perhaps: void) in the headers and it should do the trick, no?

Comment: `perl -p -i -e s/VOID/void/ *`

Comment: @piokuc that might be an option, but i'm not the only one using these headers in this repository, editing them is kind of a last resort that I’d rather not exercise.

Comment: Well, you can make a copy of it just for the purpose of creating SWIG bindings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i created my SWIG interface file, i copied the function prototypes verbatim, `VOID` and all. if i changed all of the prototypes in my interface file from using `VOID` to using `void`, the problem went away.

It seems that SWIG does respect the preprocessor, just not for it's own interface file, which is understandable.

Posting this here for future searchers...

Answer (score 0):

Hold on a second... if you do not have the source for the library, I'm assuming you mean that the `#define VOID void` happens in a header (.H) file you're including to use this library.  If the library is already compiled, then the `#define VOID void` doesn't affect it, and is only relevant in those headers.  The `#define` directives only affect your preprocessor, which compiles your code (the library is already built).  So, if only those headers use the VOID thing, then make sure that in those headers, there's a `#define VOID void` at the top, and a  `#undef VOID` at the bottom to delete the VOID macro.

Comment: Problem is, i don't think that SWIG is respecting the preprocessor. VOID is actually defined pretty early in the headers.

Comment: It's possible that other parts of the same header file rely on the `#define VOID void` definition.

Comment: What I mean is, make the VOID macro only defined in the headers.  At the top of every header, define it, and at the bottom, undefine it.  The preprocessor goes over the file in a fairly linear fashion, and doing this should make it so that VOID only means something to the library's headers, and doesn't go on to screw up other things in your code.  If that's not doable, then I guess a hard replace of VOID to void is always an option.

Comment: How would SWIG not "respect" the preprocessor?